# Is there a software to reset/flash your iphone to factory without itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, error, firmware

i have two "broken" iphones. One of them, is a 3gs. I've changed is battery yesterday and it was ok for 30 min/1hour and then it just started rebooting. I searched online and i saw it was a common problem for the 3gs, nobody knows why but i would only need the battery to be charged and then it would be ok. I've tried to restore it itunes, sucessfully, but the phone wouldn't boot to the menu... Then itunes logo "of death".

I tried restoring in DFU, normal, i've tried softwares like tiny umbrela to exit the reboot loop, but no success. In itunes it never ends recovering, and it allways pops out some error. I had probably 6 diferent errors until now. I've used a "fixreboot" file, that i think uses greenpoison code... I only know that maybe 90% of the lines it reports, are errors, and then it says "no sucessfull firmware download after 60000ms, giving up" and then it justs reboots to itunes logo again...

This phone was just upgraded, and hadn't have any jailbreak.

The other one is a iphone 4, and has the same problem... It's stuck on the Itunes logo but this one, i allways get Code 2 error on it when restoring.

I guess the only way is to make it reinstall the firmware outside itunes. Is there any software to reinstall the firmwares other than itunes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a reset button that lets you reset several different properties to factory settings. If you open 'Settings' on the phone (if you are able) and goto 'General'. At bottom of 'General' is a reset button. Tapping that brings up options for reset.

Comment: How is the user (from 2014 and a completely different version of iOS) supposed to access the Settings app when they've stated their iPhone will not boot past the Apple logo?  Please see [answer] for tips on providing good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try iFunBox, it can run on both PC/Mac.

There are actually a lot of 3rd party software able to update the iOS.

Comment: ifunbox doesn't recognize the devices in recovery mode...

Comment: "There are actually a lot of 3rd party software able to update the iOS" Do tell? A list would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of iTunes you have, [the 3gs won't upgrade past iOS 6.1.6](http://www.everyi.com/by-capability/maximum-supported-ios-version-for-ipod-iphone-ipad.html)

This [surprising page still hosts a 6.1.6 security update on the Apple website](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1722).

This [even more surprising page has iTunes version 9.2.1 which was contemporary with your 3gs](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1056). It's possible that the newest iTunes don't have the needed package for your old phone.

Try to download and [install this Windows version](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1056) (you don't specify if you have a Mac or Windows, these are Windows versions)

As a last resort, are you near an Apple store? Anyone gets their free 15 minutes of Genius bar help (a Specialist for iOS) (assuming they have not changed the policy since I worked there last year) and the Geniuses have pretty much every iOS package on the store network, so you don't have to download some scary thing from Softionic.

You [could also try here.](https://ipsw.me/) Or [if you are really desperate here](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/ios-6-1-6-untethered-jailbreak-p0sixspwn-update-released-cydia-1437872).

The last part of this answer is that your is more than likely just fried, time to [upgrade to a iPhone 4s, the oldest one that supports the latest software](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) :)